# Dynamically Generate Transparent Tracking Pixel

Tags: java, image, transparency, pixel

I'm trying to generate a clear tracking pixel dynamically in Java, but running into some issues. I have no problem returning this to the user, but I can't seem to get the pixel right. What am I doing wrong?

This is what I have, which gives me a 1x1 white pixel. How do I make this as small as possible (file size) and make it transparent?

```
BufferedImage singlePixelImage = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY_TYPE);
singlePixelImage.setRGB(0, 0, 0xFFFFFF);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the GRAY image type doesn't support transparency. Only modified Łukasz's answer to show exactly what's going on. When you create new image all of it's pixels have initial value set to 0. So that means it's completely transparent. In following code I'm making it explicitly:

```
    BufferedImage singlePixelImage = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
    Color transparent = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
    singlePixelImage.setRGB(0, 0, transparent.getRGB());

    File file = new File("pixel.png");
    try {
        ImageIO.write(singlePixelImage, "png", file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
```

Comment: Example code should not contain `Auto-generated catch block`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an adaptation of @Rekin's answer to write to a byte array instead of a file.

### Tracking Image Generated Dynamically

```
public static byte[] get1x1PixelImage() throws IOException{

    // The following code was used to generate the tracking pixel.
    BufferedImage singlePixelImage = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
    Color transparent = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
    singlePixelImage.setRGB(0, 0, transparent.getRGB());

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(singlePixelImage, "png", baos);
    byte[] imageInBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    baos.close();

    return imageInBytes;
}
```

### Get Static Tracking Image

```
// Use either format, tracking gif is smaller then the png.
static byte[] trackingGif = { 0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38, 0x39, 0x61, 0x1, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0, (byte) 0x80, 0x0, 0x0, (byte)  0xff, (byte)  0xff,  (byte) 0xff, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x2c, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x2, 0x2, 0x44, 0x1, 0x0, 0x3b };
static byte[] trackingPng = {(byte)0x89,0x50,0x4E,0x47,0x0D,0x0A,0x1A,0x0A,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x0D,0x49,0x48,0x44,0x52,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x08,0x06,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x1F,0x15,(byte)0xC4,(byte)0x89,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x0B,0x49,0x44,0x41,0x54,0x78,(byte)0xDA,0x63,0x60,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x00,0x05,0x00,0x01,(byte)0xE9,(byte)0xFA,(byte)0xDC,(byte)0xD8,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x49,0x45,0x4E,0x44,(byte)0xAE,0x42,0x60,(byte)0x82};

public static byte[] get1x1PixelImage() {
    return trackingGif;   // trackingGif is about 38 bytes where trackingPng is 68
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a tracking pixel, why would you want to generate it each time again? Generate it once, encode it as a GIF or PNG image and only send those bytes back to the HTTP client. That's much easier.

Comment: I'm not generating it each time. The issue is with the pixel itself.

Comment: I think that `TYPE_BYTE_GRAY_TYPE` doesn't support transparency. Try RGBA (red, green, blue, alpha) instead.

Comment: I did, but I'm clueless about the int value to pass in. Any ideas?

Comment: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) may help

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is enough to create a BufferedImage with proper type. It's not necessary to call setRGB method. Try this:

```
BufferedImage singlePixelImage = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
   
// then I'm saving the generated image in file:
File file = new File("pixel.png");
try {
   ImageIO.write(singlePixelImage, "png", file);
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I've checked pixel.png file in Adobe PhotoShop and it was transparent.

`BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR` tells to add an additional, fourth byte which stores information about alpha channel value (transparency of a pixel).

Comment: Example code should not contain `Auto-generated catch block`.

Comment: Thank you @RolandIllig - eventually, after 12 years someone noticed that!